# USD Tethering speed different as compare to windows on ubuntu 15

Tags: 14.04, usb, tethering

I am using internet from mobile device to laptop using USD Tethering.

The speed I am getting on windows 10 using speedtest and fast.com is 5 MBPS

When I login to ubuntu 15 using dual boot, I am getting speed in 800 KBPS.

What should I do to get same speed as windows 10

Any idea?

-Thanks
Shahab

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be using any Ubuntu 15.xx as they are EoL, no longer supported. I suggest you test it in a 16.04 live session - it may work much better - and install that either way.

Comment: Which device are you using? Also how are you measuring your speeds in both the OSes? To check if any other application is hogging your speed, install `nethogs` - `sudo apt-get install nethogs`. Then, run it as root - `sudo nethogs`.

Comment: @Raphael - In order to install online any software, software repositories are required and the user doesn't have those because of the EoL version he/she is using.

Comment: @CelticWarrior - Not necessary. He/she can download the deb file from [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/nethogs) and install it using `sudo dpkg -i <package>`, though EOL for Wily still stands and he/she might not be getting the proper support for that.

Comment: @Raphael - Apt-get (or apt) - your suggestion - requires software repositories. DPKG installs **local** files (how they got there is irrelevant, they could have been copied from other physical media) therefore it's not what I meant when I said "install online". And yes, of course the EoL still stands and as you know, we shouldn't be giving support to that.

Comment: Hi, 
I have upgraded the ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 LTS.Still I am getting speed of 500 KBPS which less than same mobile tethering on windows 10 with 5 MBPS speed. 
Also install and check nethogs

Any idea?